# How to make mouseover popup window on citated text based on ID by xslt's JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt

I am using the below XML code for fig, table, reference citation. when i mouseover on the citation, it should shown the related text based on id and href.

**XML code for Citation:**

```
Fig. <link href="#ecog340-fig-0001"/>

Table. <link href="#ecog340-tbl-0005"/>

Glen and Dickman <link href="#bib-0020"/>
```

**XML code for text:**

***Figure:***

```
<figure xml:id="ecog340-fig-0001">
<mediaResourceGroup>
<mediaResource alt="image" href="urn:x-wiley:16000587:media:ecog340:ecog340-fig-0001"/>
<mediaResource alt="image" mimeType="image/png" href="image_n/ecog340-fig-0001.png" rendition="webOriginal" />
<mediaResource alt="image" mimeType="image/gif" href="image_t/ecog340-fig-0001-t.gif" rendition="webLoRes" />
<mediaResource alt="image" mimeType="image/png" href="image_m/ecog340-fig-0001-m.png" rendition="webHiRes" />
</mediaResourceGroup>
<caption>
<p>............</p>
</caption>
</figure>
```

***Table:***

```
<tabular xml:id="ecog340-tbl-1">
<title type="main">....</title>
<table colsep="0" frame="topbot" pgwide="1" rowsep="0">
<tgroup cols="4" align="left">
<colspec colnum="1" colname="col1"/>
<colspec colnum="2" colname="col2"/>
<thead valign="bottom">
<row rowsep="1">
<entry align="left">xxxxxxxx</entry>
<entry align="left">xxxxx</entry>
</row>
</thead>
<tbody>
<row>
<entry align="left" nameend="col4" namest="col1">xxxxxxx</entry>
</row>
</tbody>
</tgroup>
</table>
</tabular>
```

***Reference:***

```
<bib xml:id="bib-0020"><citation type="journal" xml:id="cit-0020"><author><familyName>xxxxxxx</familyName>, <givenNames>X. X.</givenNames></author>. <pubYear year="2005">2005</pubYear>. <articleTitle>xxxxxxxxx</articleTitle>. &#x2013; <journalTitle>xxxxx</journalTitle>. <vol>xx</vol>: <pageFirst>xxxx</pageFirst>&#x2013;<pageLast>xxx</pageLast>.</citation></bib>
```

Fig and their caption, table and their caption and corresponded reference should displayed, when i move on the citation text.

Now i am using the below script in my ***another project's XSLT***.

```
   <script language="javascript">
   var popupWindow = null;
   function positionedPopup(url,winName,w,h,t,l,scroll){
   settings =
   'height='+h+',width='+w+',top='+t+',left='+l+',scrollbars='+scroll+',resizable'
   popupWindow = window.open(url,winName,settings)
   }
   </script>


    <xsl:template match="aff"><br/><a name="{@id}" style="color:#817339" title="Affiliation" onclick="positionedPopup(this.href,'myWindow','800','100','100','200','yes');return false"><xsl:apply-templates select="@id"/>&#x00A0;: </a> <xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xref"><a href="#{@rid}" title="xref" onclick="positionedPopup(this.href,'myWindow','800','500','100','200','yes');return false"><xsl:apply-templates/></a></xsl:template>
```

However, its going to related text in new window with full article, when i click on the citation.
But it should shown the corresponded text only.

because i dont know how to open popup text by mouseover or onClick?

Could you please help me to make **mouseover** or **onClick** popup?

Please refer this site

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3528816/

please write JS for POPUP.........

Thanks...

Comment: Now, i have edited and added my old JS in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to insert the JavaScript in your XSLT. Just have one <script src="..."> tag with the necessary code in your header. With jQuery you can just write something simple such as:

```
jQuery(".icons").hover(function()
  {
     ...popup code goes here...
  });
```

So once you get the transformation to generate proper HTML, the rest is just a little script.

Comment: Hi, i need JS for popup window. if you want to see sample, please refer this url "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3528816/".

Comment: Yeah, you may end up having to do some work... I have one for my environment (Snap! C++ Websites) here: http://sourceforge.net/p/snapcpp/code/ci/master/tree/snapwebsites/plugins/output/  Search for the popup.js file.

Comment: thanks, i am a learner. i need the JS for popup window, relevant CSS and how to handle the JS in My XSLT?